# is there a open source backward static slicing tool in Java that is actually maintained and easy to use?

Tags: java, static-analysis

A backward slice identifies those statements that affect the value of the attribute.

For example:

```
x = 1;
y = 2;
z = y-2;
r = x;
z = x+y; /* the slice point is the end of the program */.
```

Here, backward slice would be:

```
x = 1;
y = 2;
z = x+y;
```

I have looked into WALA [1] and Soot [2] for the support of Slicing. However, they work the 3 address code and there is no straight forward way to extract slicing information giving the actual source code.

In fact, so far I am yet to came across a single slicing tool that works and maintained.

Can anyone please help me with my query?

[1] https://github.com/wala/WALA
[2] https://github.com/soot-oss/soot